# Draw non-overlapping lines between objects

Tags: optimization, heuristics, graph-drawing

Here is a problem, I found and would be interested in
finding first steps to get further in thinking about
solutions:

given a set of n objects (rectangles, circles and similar forms),
the task to solve is to draw lines to connect
some pairs of them (the result should be a kind of flowchart diagram).

The lines should not cross the objects and they should look as simple
as possible (shortest pathes between the objects without crossing,
as straight as possible (no sharp kinks/bends) in the lines.

I guess this could be a combinatorial optimization poblem.
Does there perhaps exist a standard heuristics?
I know, that the graphviz/dot language has some kind of heuristics
for problems like that, but I dont know, how they work.

Is it a simplex-type optimization problem?

Would it be promising to try reinforcement learning on this task?

Does there propably exist a good approximation algorithm, so one would not need to
find exact solutions for the optimal line pathes?